# Laravel change boolean depending on route

Tags: vue.js

I created a landing page using VueJS, and wrote a script to change the app bars elevation depending on whether the user is on the home page or not. However, I now need to convert all of this into laravel, and everything else works apart from the ability to change the elevation depending on the link. This is the code I am using currently, how would I translate that into laravel?

```js
watch: {
    '$route'() {
      if (this.$route.path === '/') {
        this.isFlat = false
      }
      else {
        this.isFlat = true
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: So you mean the frontend is baked into a `blade.php` file? So then you can use PHP code and determine the current route from there?
Or use javascript `document.location.pathname` to check the current path?

Comment: The frontend is in a Vue component, and I'm calling that component in the home.blade  In normal VueJS the code above checks what path the user is on and runs everytime theres a change, so if they change to /about the navbar will change from an elevated navbar to a flat one. However I am struggling to replicate this on laravel

Comment: Your code implies you are using vue router for routing. So if you are not using vue-router anymore, but laravel routing, then you will have a page refresh for every link click. Than you can, for example, just use the `created()` hook and use `document.location.pathname` to detect whether you are at `'/'`.